# Using jmeter how to check if an element is present in an array or not

Tags: jmeter

trying to check "x" is present or not in {"a","b","c","d"}

```
String a="x";

String[] ids = {"a","b","c","d"};
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using beanshell

String a="x";

String[] ids = {"a","b","c","d"};

if(Arrays.asList(ids).contains(a)!= true)

{

```
log.info("Value is New");
```

}